# How to show a div with an if/else statement after response is received

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a form where all the questions are separated into different pages(divs) but I am showing and hiding the pages. When a user gets a response back from the api where their status is "accepted", they get redirected to a URL. I am trying to figure out how to show a div if their status is "rejected".

The response looks like:

```
{status: "REJECTED", redirectUrl: null, loanID: null, errors: Array(0), rejectReason: "Existing Customer", …}
```

My if/elsestatement looks like

```
if(b.status == "ACCEPTED") {
  window.location = b.redirectURL;
}
else {
  // not sure
}
```

I have tried the below method but that does not work.

```
document.getElementById('page18').style.visibility = "visible";
```

Here is what the end portion of my form looks like.

Page 17 is what the user lands on after they have hit the submit button and page 18 is the reject page that I would like them to get redirected to if they get a rejected response.

```
<!---PAGE 16 -->

<div id="page17" class="pageform">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">Thank you for your submission!</h3>
  <h4 style="text-align: center;"> Please wait one moment while we process your application.</h4> <br> <br>
  <div class="loading">Loading…</div>
</div>

<!---REJECT PAGE -->

<div id="page18" class="pageform">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">Sorry, we were unable to fund your request at this time.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: use display style, not the visibility style  ex: document.getElementById('page18').style.display= "block";

Comment: did you tried **document.getElementById('page18').style.display='block'**

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thank you so much, it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using below code in your css:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

in javascript to show your div you have to use:

```
document.getElementById('page18').style.visibility = "visible";
```

but if you are using display in your css:

```
display: none;
```

in javascript to show this item you have to use:

```
document.getElementById('page18').style.display='block';
```

Comment: I am using 
```
visibility: hidden;
```
except setting the visibility to visible does not work. For some reason, it works by changing display to "block" though. Thank you!